# Simplify php array from 5 variable to 2 variables

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array $bobby with the following arrays inside. It is sorted by id.

```
1
    id="1"  
    color="blue"
    size="7"
    height="10"
    beebop="z"

2
    id="2"  
    color="red"
    size="64"
    height="52"
    beebop="y"
3
    id="3"  
    color="pink"
    size="72"
    height="39"
    beebop="not_x"
```

I am having trouble creating the php function that will create a simplified array (`$bobby_simplified`) which only contains two values, id and color?  So, the new array would look like this:

```
1
    id="1"  
    color="blue"
2
    id="2"  
    color="red"
3
    id="3"  
    color="pink"
```

Also, in that function, can we sort by color ascending?

---

I tried the following but with no luck:

```
            foreach ($bobby AS $bobby_simplified) {
                $id = $bobby_simplified['id'];
                $color = $bobby_simplified['color'];
            }
```

Comment: `Can I create a php function to create a new array` - yes. What have you tried? `can we sort by color ascending?` - yes. There's plenty of questions on how to sort arrays in PHP on Stackoverflow, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php).

Comment: Thanks Robbie Averill. I added the function I tried for the first part.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `array_map()` function to get an new array, and `array_slice()` to get first two elements of the subarray. Check the **[live demo](https://eval.in/790868)**.

```
$simplified = array_map(function($v){return array_slice($v, 0, 2, true);}, $array);
```

Comment: Thanks Kris Roofe:  In your fxn, I take it $v=$bobby in my function and $array=$bobby_simplified?

Comment: $array is you unsimplified array, the array_map() funciton's output is you simplified array.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the array alphabetically by color using:

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) { return strcmp($a['color'], $b['color']); });
```

Comment: have you read OP question properly ? he does'nt want to sort array, you may get down votes

Comment: Towards the bottom of his question he has `Also, in that function, can we sort by color ascending?`

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

> > foreach ($bobby AS $bobby_simplified){
> >  $res = array("id"=>$bobby_simplified['id'],"color"=>$bobby_simplified['color']);
> >     
> > }
> > print_r($res);

Comment: `$res` is going to continuously get overwritten, you probably meant `$res[]`

Answer (score -1):

try this, already tested, added sorting by color

```
$array = [1=>['id'=> '1', 'color'=> 'blue', 'size'=>'7', 'height'=>'10', 'beebop'=>'z'],
          2=>['id'=> '2', 'color'=> 'red', 'size'=>'64', 'height'=>'52', 'beebop'=>'y'],
          3=>['id'=> '3', 'color'=> 'pink', 'size'=>'72', 'height'=>'39', 'beebop'=>'not_x'],
         ];

foreach($array as $arr){

        $arr = array_splice($arr,0,2);
        print_r($arr); 

        $array2[] = $arr;
}
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($array2);

    echo "<br>";



function sortBy($field, &$array, $direction = 'asc')
{
    usort($array, create_function('$a, $b', '
        $a = $a["' . $field . '"];
        $b = $b["' . $field . '"];

        if ($a == $b)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return ($a ' . ($direction == 'desc' ? '>' : '<') .' $b) ? -1 : 1;
    '));

    return true;
}

sortBy('color',   $array2, 'asc');
print_r($array2);
```